# One specific coil on stove trips circuit breaker

Tags: circuit-breaker, oven, range

I recently purchased a home with appliances included. One of the appliances is an stove/oven.

We cleaned the range before our first use. The day after the clean, we used the oven and 3 of the 4 coils on the stove top. Later in the day we tried to use 3 coils again, but this time using the back left coil (which we previously had not used). As soon as I turned it on, the circuit breaker flipped. I reset the circuit breaker, tried the same range again and this time it seemed like it blew the fuse in the range itself.

So, naturally I tried it again. This time the breaker will not stay in the on position if the coil is in range. I took the coil out, the breaker will once again switch to on position. Stove works, just cant use or insert that last coil.

Can anyone point me toward similar issues? It seems to be more specific than the entire range going out.

Comment: The FIRST time it tripped when you went to use that coil didn't clue you in that something was VERY wrong?? You had to try it two more times? It takes a heck of a lot to flip the breaker on a range circuit. Throw the coil out!

Answer (score 3):

You know those coils are cheap, consumable, field-replaceable items.   It's common for departing tenants to replace drip pans and coils that are too dirty to clean easily.

The coil may have lost some of its insulation and developed a short to chassis. But generally they are not valuable enough to ask "why".

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the coil is shorted and providing far less of a resistive heating path than it should be. It should be trashed and replaced as I don't think there is a way to fix that coil, unless you can specifically see the short between the two prongs that plug into the range.